# How to delete cells from a table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have an Edit button in my navigation bar, and I have an table view.

My edit button calls an -editAction method.

And then, I have this piece of code to delete a cell, but I don't know how I can make the edit button to call this code...or how the edit button can let the table view display those red delete circles for every cell, which then trigger this:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the managed object at the given index path
        NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];

        // Update Event objects array and table view
        [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        // Commit the change
        NSError *error;
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Handle the error
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `UITableView` class reference docs, the code:

```
tableView.editing = YES;
```

Should put the table into editing mode and display those red delete circles. Then when the user deletes a cell your data source method should be called.

You can also use `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];` for an animated effect

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller's -viewDidLoad method add the Edit button:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

This button will toggle the controller's editing mode, sending it -setEditing:animated:

Comment: Where does the editButtonItem come from? There is no such property in UITableView or UITableViewController, and in the entire example code no editButtonItem is defined either. Confusing...

Comment: It's from category UIViewControllerEditing for UIViewController, see UIViewController.h.

Comment: Costique, this looks like a good answer, but is this specific to UITableViewController? Otherwise not sure how the UITableView gets the setEditing:animated: message? OP wasn't specific about view controller class, which is why I gave my answer but your answer would be preferable if this is the case. Thanks

Comment: UIViewControllerEditing protocol defines this method for any UIViewController, including UITableViewController and your own UIViewController subclasses: -(UIBarButtonItem *)editButtonItem. In other words, the standard Edit/Done button is provided for all view controllers absolutely for free. The button's target is set to the controller, its action is set to -setEditing: automatically. There's just no reason not to use it :)