# Custom UITableView Editing Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview inside a viewcontroller I would like to edit/delete rows. It is not inside a navigation controller. I have a button set up to call this method:

```
-(IBAction)setEditingStyleOfTable{
    [favsTable setEditing:TRUE animated:TRUE];
}
```

The editing buttons appear in my cells correctly, either by tapping that button or swiping the row, however, the edit buttons do not respond to any events. They just show up and do nothing. Any thoughts as to why?

I have the standard delegate methods for setting the editing style of the table as well, so I won't put them here, unless requested.

Comment: How do you want the user to edit the cells? There's like a million of ways...

Comment: I guess by edit, I specifically mean delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this post, it uses a managedObject instead of an Array, just substitute your Array (datasource for populating tableView) and you'll figure it out.

[How to delete cells from a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071302/how-to-delete-cells-from-a-table-view)